# Keeping track of Objects created in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

I have a class called Orders.  I want to keep an array of all the "Orders" instances so I can .each map/reduce/or otherwise query them.

Later I would like to Marshal "dump" and "load" the "Orders" array of objects.

My plan is to add each new object created onto an @@all_orders array stack on initialization.  Then I can do my .each method on the @@all_orders array, looping through all "orders" objects.

Am I approaching this the right OOP way? (code snippet to get the idea)...

```
class Orders

  @@all_orders = Array.new
  attr_accessor :order_no, :customer

  def initialize(order_no, customer)
    @id, @customer = order_no, customer
    @order_lines = Array.new
    @@all_orders << self
  end
```

Comment: As a note, it's almost always preferable to use the short `[ ]` notation instead of `Array.new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper Object-Oriented way to do this is to have a container you're putting the orders into. This can be a plain-old array or a special container class.

The big problem here is you don't have a proper context for storing the "all orders" data. All orders relevant to what? The entire application? If that's the case you need the concept of an order book or a database to store them.

For example:

```
class OrderBook < Array
end

order_book = OrderBook.new
order_book << Order.new(...)
```

Note that I've renamed `Orders` to `Order` as that's more accurate, singular name.

Auto-*magically* adding instances to a container is almost always a recipe for disaster. That sort of thing should be handled using a design pattern like *model-controller*. It's a huge assumption that you'd want to include it in the global orders pool.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using [dependency injection](http://www.sandimetz.com/blog/2009/03/21/solid-design-principles) to pass in a list object to your order instances. Best practice in OOP is to decouple code and try to give each object only one responsibility (the Single Responsibility Principle). This helps keep your code maintainable and easily changeable. The way you're approaching it now, the `Order` class is doing both order-related stuff AND storage of the list. In my example below, a list object can be passed to the `Order` object when the order is instantiated and all the order need know is that the list object should respond to the `#add` method. This way, if the implementation for the list has to change, like making the list object use a Redis store, for example, then you don't need to change both the `Order` class and the `OrderList` class. You would only update the `OrderList` class to deal with Redis in the `#add` method. Additionally, you no longer have an internal dependency in the `Order` class for handling list responsibilities, so the order is only doing what it should be.

```
class OrderList
  attr_reader :items

  def initialize
    @items = []
  end

  def add(order)
    @items << order
  end
end

class Order
  def initialize(opts)
    order_list = opts[:order_list]
    order_list.add self
  end
end

order_list = OrderList.new
order1 = Order.new order_list: order_list
order2 = Order.new order_list: order_list

puts order_list.list.inspect
```